Loading multiple images inside a custom notification with RemoteViews
I'm trying to create a custom notification that has 4 ImageViews in it. When I try to add the images, if I add only one it works, but when I try to add a second one it shows nothing.
Here is the function where I create the notification
private void createNotification() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RateDia.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        RemoteViews layoutNotificacio = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notificacio_gran);
        layoutNotificacio.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imatge1, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e01_grinning_face));
        layoutNotificacio.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imatge2, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e02_grimacing_face));
        layoutNotificacio.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imatge3, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e03_grinning_face_with_smiling_eyes));
        layoutNotificacio.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imatge4, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e04_face_with_tears_of_joy));

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mimismo_icono_notificacio)
                .setContentTitle("Notificación de miMismo")
                .setCustomBigContentView(layoutNotificacio)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        }
    }

And here is the xml for the Remote View:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imatge1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/e01_grinning_face" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imatge2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/e02_grimacing_face" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imatge3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/e04_face_with_tears_of_joy" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imatge4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />


</LinearLayout>

The source of the images is set for testing the layout, but must be changed programmatically and there is where the problem occurs.
As you can see, there are 4 lines like this:
layoutNotificacio.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imatge1, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e01_grinning_face));
If I comment or delete three of them, I'll see an image in the notification. If I have 2 or more nothing is shown.
Any help would be appreciated.

What are the resolutions of your four images, and in what res/ subdirectory are they located?

They are emojis of 256x256 pixels and are inside Drawables


are inside Drawables

If you mean res/drawable/, stop using that directory. That is a synonym for res/drawable-mdpi/, and it means Android may be scaling your images when that is not needed or wanted. Instead, either put the images in res/drawable-anydpi/ (to say that they do not need to be scaled based on screen density) or set up per-density versions of your images in the proper density-specific directories (e.g., res/drawable-hdpi/, res/drawable-xhdpi/).
To your original problem, try using setImageViewResource() instead of setImageViewBitmap(). This will simplify your code and dramatically reduce the amount of memory used in your RemoteViews update.

Thanks! It seems that the problem was with setImageViewBitmap. I changed it for .setImageViewSource and now it's working. I think that was a novice error. Thanks so much!
